# Which time format does ESA use for Sentinel-3 file names?

Tags: time, date, naming-conventions, esa, sentinel-3

regarding the ESA Sentinel-3 file name convention I have got a question; which **time zone (GMT, CEST, ...)** does ESA use? I could not find anything yet, even it should be a critical point for many users...

There is no information given on the official website of ESA for the Sentinel-3 SLSTR-product as you can see here URL:https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-3-slstr/naming-convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the UTC time format according to the official [source1](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-3-altimetry/definitions/conventions), [source2](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-3-slstr/level-1/calibration-mode-desc):

> The time reference system in the SRAL/MWR Level-2 products is the Universal Time Coordinated (UTC).

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, @Mr. Che ! i hope this counts not just for Level 2 products, but also for Level 1B products?

Comment: @ExploreR See update

Answer (score 0):

It is right there in the link you provided:

> The file naming convention of SLSTR products (see this document for more details) is identified by the sequence of fields described below:
>
> MMM_SL_L_TTTTTT_yyyymmddThhmmss_YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS_YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS_[instance ID]*GGG*[class ID].SEN3
>
> [...]
>
> yyyymmddThhmmss is the sensing start time
>
> YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS is the sensing stop time
>
> YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS is the product creation date
>
> [...]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, @Erik that´s what i have found out so far, but i am talking about the time format; UTC, CEST, GMT...

Comment: That's the time zone ;-)